# Dynamic border offset with merged cells

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to add borders to a sheet where the data is dynamic in both rows and columns. I have figured out out how add the borders to a single column, but not to the rest of the columns that I want. Right now I have the following:

```
Dim x As Range, y As Range
Set y = Range("F5:F200")

For Each x In y
    If x = "SPACE" Then
    ElseIf x <> "" Then
        x.Offset(0, 2).Borders.LineStyle = xlContinuous
    End If
Next x
```

which ends up looking like this:

[image]

How do I stop the borders in rows 6, 15, 33, and 57 pushing to the right (it won't always be those rows that have the merged cells)? Is that because of the merged cells?

Also, how do I make the border to the right equal the count from cell `F1` (17 in this case is the number of dates I have from May 28 to Aug 31. These are user defined inputs so will change each time)?

Comment: Merged cells are generally a bad idea. You can use center across selection instead.

Comment: While merged cells are generally a bad idea, they can also be worked with by accessing the `.Areas` property of the range.

Comment: @ScottHoltzman - [`.MergeArea`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.mergearea) right?